# SVN auto-update keeps a service running

Tags: windows, svn, coldfusion

I'm using a Windows scheduled task to run SVN's command line auto-update. Every time the task runs it is starting a new tortoiseproc.exe process and they never stop, so I end up with hundreds of running processes. What am I doing wrong? Here's the batch file:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"D:\Path\To\Root" /closeonend:1
```

Here's the task settings:

> - Run whether logged in or not
> - Run with highest privileges
> - Repeat every 15 minutes
> - Start the batch file
> - Wake to run the task
> - Allow to run on-demand
> - Run task as soon as possible after schedule start missed
> - Stop if runs longer than 1 hour
> - If does not end when requested force stop

I can't post images but imagine the processes section of Task Manager having hundreds of tortoiseproc.exe entries, one for each running instance.

Answer (score 1):

This part

> /closeonend:1

means

> auto close if no errors

Meaning that if the first one failed for some reason, the dialog window will be kept open. Any following calls will probably fail with "cleanup required" and also be left open :(

I do not believe there is a robust way to do this with TortoiseSVN.
Since i have the same problem i am now looking at either subversion command line client or SlikSVN.